# How to Sign-In to Google Across Multiple Activities

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-signin

When I sign in through Google Sign-In to ActivityA, I want ActivityB to sign in to the same account simultaneously and and have all the capabilities of ActivityA. When I sign-out of ActivityB, I want it to also sign out of ActivityA.

For example, I have a HomeActivity using Google's PlusApi and then I have a MapsActivity that will be used for my navigation and all other Api Services I want to include.

1) Is this possible?

2) Is this the best way to do this and/or is there a better way to do it?

Here is my Code:

HomeActivity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person;

public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        View.OnClickListener {

    /* Request code used to invoke sign in user interactions. */
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

    /* Keys for persisting instance variables in savedInstanceState */
    private static final String KEY_IS_RESOLVING = "is_resolving";
    private static final String KEY_SHOULD_RESOLVE = "should_resolve";

    /* Client used to interact with Google APIs. */
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /* View to display current status (signed-in, signed-out, disconnected, etc) */
    private TextView mStatus;

    /* Is there a ConnectionResult resolution in progress? */
    private boolean mIsResolving = false;

    /* Should we automatically resolve ConnectionResults when possible? */
    private boolean mShouldResolve = false;
    private static final String TAG = "SignInActivity";
//
//    private ProgressBar spinner;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        // Restore from saved instance state
        // [START restore_saved_instance_state]
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mIsResolving = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_IS_RESOLVING);
            mShouldResolve = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_SHOULD_RESOLVE);
        }

        // [END restore_saved_instance_state]

        // Set up button click listeners
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.disconnect_button).setOnClickListener(this);

//        spinner = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.sign_in_loading);
//        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//        Log.w(TAG, "Spinner is visible");
//
//
//        findViewById(R.id.login_screen).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        // Large sign-in
        ((SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button)).setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);

        // Start with sign-in button disabled until sign-in either succeeds or fails
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setEnabled(false);

        // Set up view instances
        mStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);

        // Build GoogleApiClient to request access to the basic user profile
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
                .build();


    }

    private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
            // Show signed-in user's name
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            if (currentPerson != null) {
                String name = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                mStatus.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_fmt, name));
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, getString(R.string.error_null_person));
                mStatus.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_err));
            }

            // Set button visibility
            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Log.w(TAG, "UI has been updated.");
        } else {
            // Show signed-out message
            mStatus.setText(R.string.signed_out);

            // Set button visibility
            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setEnabled(true);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        // onConnected indicates that an account was selected on the device, that the selected
        // account has granted any requested permissions to our app and that we were able to
        // establish a service connection to Google Play services.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected:" + bundle);

        // Show the signed-in UI

        updateUI(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        // The connection to Google Play services was lost. The GoogleApiClient will automatically
        // attempt to re-connect. Any UI elements that depend on connection to Google APIs should
        // be hidden or disabled until onConnected is called again.
        Log.w(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended:" + i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                // User clicked the sign-in button, so begin the sign-in process and automatically
                // attempt to resolve any errors that occur.
                mStatus.setText(R.string.signing_in);
                // [START sign_in_clicked]
                mShouldResolve = true;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                // [END sign_in_clicked]
                                break;
            case R.id.sign_out_button:
                // Clear the default account so that GoogleApiClient will not automatically
                // connect in the future.
                // [START sign_out_clicked]
                if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                }
                // [END sign_out_clicked]
                updateUI(false);
                break;
            case R.id.disconnect_button:
                // Revoke all granted permissions and clear the default account.  The user will have
                // to pass the consent screen to sign in again.
                // [START disconnect_clicked]
                if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                    Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient);
                    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                }
                // [END disconnect_clicked]
                updateUI(false);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // Could not connect to Google Play Services.  The user needs to select an account,
        // grant permissions or resolve an error in order to sign in. Refer to the javadoc for
        // ConnectionResult to see possible error codes.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);

        if (!mIsResolving && mShouldResolve) {
            if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
                try {
                    connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
                    mIsResolving = true;
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not resolve ConnectionResult.", e);
                    mIsResolving = false;
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
            } else {
                // Could not resolve the connection result, show the user an
                // error dialog.
                showErrorDialog(connectionResult);
            }
        } else {
            // Show the signed-out UI
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult:" + requestCode + ":" + resultCode + ":" + data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            // If the error resolution was not successful we should not resolve further.
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                mShouldResolve = false;
            }

            mIsResolving = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();

            Intent startMaps = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
            HomeActivity.this.startActivity(startMaps);
        }
    }

    private void showErrorDialog(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        int errorCode = connectionResult.getErrorCode();

        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(errorCode)) {
            // Show the default Google Play services error dialog which may still start an intent
            // on our behalf if the user can resolve the issue.
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode, this, RC_SIGN_IN,
                    new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            mShouldResolve = false;
                            updateUI(false);
                        }
                    }).show();
        } else {
            // No default Google Play Services error, display a message to the user.
            String errorString = getString(R.string.play_services_error_fmt, errorCode);
            Toast.makeText(this, errorString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            mShouldResolve = false;
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }

}
```

MapsActivity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener,
        View.OnClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    private HomeActivity  mHomeActivity = new HomeActivity();

    public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        //Create the LocationRequest object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10*1000)           //10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000);   //1 second, in milliseconds

        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.disconnect_button).setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map){
        //Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()  {
        super.onPause();
        if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())  {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
     * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
     * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
     * <p/>
     * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
     * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
     * <p/>
     * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
     * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
     * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
     * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
     * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
     */
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
     * just add a marker near Africa.
     * <p/>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
     */
    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    private void handleNewLocation(Location location)   {
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());

        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latlng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location==null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
        else {
            handleNewLocation(location);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution())   {
            try {
                //Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sign_out_button:
                // Clear the default account so that GoogleApiClient will not automatically
                // connect in the future.
                // [START sign_out_clicked]
//                if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
//                    Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
//                    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
//                }
                // [END sign_out_clicked]
                Intent startHomeDisconnect = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                MapsActivity.this.startActivity(startHomeDisconnect);
                break;
            case R.id.disconnect_button:
                // Revoke all granted permissions and clear the default account.  The user will have
                // to pass the consent screen to sign in again.
                // [START disconnect_clicked]
//                if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
//                    Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
//                    Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient);
//                    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
//                }
                // [END disconnect_clicked]
                Intent startHomeSignOut = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                MapsActivity.this.startActivity(startHomeSignOut);
                break;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You may want to create a singleton and communicate it with passing listener interface to it for various states.